# SQL Server: Update only 1 of multiple completely duplicate records

Tags: sql-server, ssis

This one is bugging me.

I am working in a data warehousing staging table where there can potentially be rows where the column values are 100% duplicates of others. There are dozens of columns, but for the sake of this argument, lets use the following example:

```
tblExample (ID Int, Active bit, ModifiedDate DateTime)
```

Now, at any given time there is only supposed to be one record per ID that has Active set to 1. All others should have active set to 0. There is a process that enforces this during the data loading.

That process can and has broken in the past, resulting in data like this:

```
ID     Active ModifiedDate
123456 0      2016-05-27 12:37:46.111
123456 1      2016-05-27 12:37:46.433
123456 1      2016-05-27 12:37:46.433
```

In that case there are 2 "Identical" records that have Active set to 1.
I need to find a way to make only one of those records active = 1.

Now the process I am using to do this currently assumes that the Date value is unique and in 99.99% of the times that IS the case. But there are times when the date will also be duplicated. And I can't for the life of me figure out a way to update only a single one of those records, since I have nothing to latch on to for the WHERE.

- I cannot add or modify the schema.
- This is all happening inside [ssis](/questions/tagged/ssis), so I am limited to the restrictions inherent with that platform (Some things just don't work well in SSIS)

Ideas?

Comment: This is why primary keys are important.

Comment: Well the very first workaround I can see of is to update it all to zero and then update just the one that has the max date limiting it to one.

Comment: Just thinking and I'm faaaar from a pro (hence writing it as a comment), but can you create a CTE with `Select top 1 ...` and then update the CTE?

Comment: I just read it all again and you don't want to update **just one** you need to make just one with value one, which means you may be updating more than one rows! Am I right ?

Comment: "(Some things just don't work well in SSIS)" that's the understatement of a lifetime

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
with a as(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by ID, Active, ModifiedDate order by ModifiedDate) as rn from tblExample
)       

update a set active = 0 where rn >1
select * from tblExample;
```

[Here is an example](http://rextester.com/CGEM15574) with your data.

Create a CTE with `Row_number()` for dupes on `ModifiedDate`(as your solution works for non-dupes of `ModifiedDate`) and updates the CTE, updating your data.

If you want to replace your process you could use the below:

```
with a as(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by ID, Active order by ModifiedDate desc) as rn from tblExample
)

update a set active = 0 where rn >1
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by ID, A order by ModifiedDate desc) as rn from tblExample;
```

This only allows the most recent entry for each `ID` to be active

[Alternative solution](http://rextester.com/MROVU58989)

Comment: Will CTE work in SSIS? I admit I have not tried, but I will be very surprised if it does. As I said, SSIS is very very limited. I will try just to see.

Comment: @DavidBorneman It should! You may need to add a ';' semi-colon before setting it: '; with a as...'  If for some reason CTE doesnt work (different connections etc) you could create a temp table with the RowNumber() and load values back into your table